# Using .htaccess to bypass Zend Framework and run different framework in sub directory

Tags: php, .htaccess, zend-framework, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to run a non-Zend php application within a sub directory of a Zend site. I'd like to bypass the Zend application for all files within the sub directory '/branches' in .htaccess. So far none of the solutions I've found have worked. Here is the current .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

# WWW Resolve
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^web/content/(.*)$ http://www.domain.com/$1 [R=301,L]

# Eliminate Trailing Slash
RewriteRule web/content/(.+)/$ http://www.domain.com/$1 [R=301,L]

# Route Requests
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]
```

Can this even accomplished in .htaccess?

Comment: I don't see anything in here that indicates you tried any rewrite rules related to /branches Can you show us what you tried that didn't work?  Are you looking for a straight pass-through of those requests, or do they need their own rewrite logic?

Comment: I'd like a straight pass through of anything within '/branches'. I've tried the following:
`RewriteRule !(branches)$ index.php - [NC,L]` 
`RewriteRule ^branches/$ branches/index.php [L,QSA]` 
`RewriteRule ^blog - [NC,L]` 
and many variations on those.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able solve this without altering .htaccess and instead just placing my sub directory within '/content'.

Answer (score 1):

You currently have:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]
```

This makes no sense, as the RewriteCond you have specified to basically not do anything for actual files, directories, and symlinks will never work. This is because, that RewriteRule is followed immediately by the rule to rewrite EVERYTHING to index.php.

If your intent is to direct everything that is not a request to a real directory of file to index.php, you should have something like this:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]
```

And to add the special case of ignoring `/branches` just add one condition like this:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !^branches/
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]
```

Comment: That's actually the default Zend .htaccess. Applying those changes breaks the Zend application.

Comment: The [NC,L] would mean that the RewriteRule doesn't execute any other rules, so yes, Ryan's original htaccess does work.